# In intellij idea 12, is there any settings can filter out files that I don't want to list in project view?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Some files or directories like *.iml, .idea, .settings, .gitignore, etc.

Is there any settings can filter out these files.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`File` | `Settings` | `File Types` | **Ignore files and folders**.
[image]

Comment: Ah I thought one had to create a custom Scope to filter out the files from Project view but this works fine. Thanks !

Comment: More details on [IntelliJ IDEA Blog](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2011/04/intellij-idea-does-not-show-some-files-know-the-hiding-places/).

Answer (score 1):

`project structure > modules >` exclude directories/files as you like

Comment: I have tried, but it only can exclude directories, files cannot be excluded.